Collation support for Synapse Lake Databases
I have got a synapse lake database and I am wondering how to change its collation or whether there is a way to create a new lake database with a different collation.
When I run the below query in SSMS connected to synapse SQL end point I get the following result
--query 
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX(DB_NAME(), 'Collation') AS Collation;

--result 
Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8

When I run the below query with and Upper case C on 'Capital'
--query
SELECT Name   FROM [dbo].[tablename]  where [Name] ='Capital' 
--It returns me the results 
'Capital' 

However when I run it with a lower case c, 'capital' it does not return results.
Then I ran the query with
SELECT Name   FROM [dbo].[tablename]  where [Name] ='capital'  COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS --Note lower case c

and It returns the results
'Capital' --upper case c

I tried changing the collation and it gives the the below error
ALTER DATABASE [Dbname] COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8;

Error:
 Msg 15875, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
    Operation ALTER DATABASE is not allowed for a replicated database.

Completion time: 2024-05-08T10:29:04.5507346+01:00

Any thoughts are much Appreciated

Can you provide the details of what is your blocker and along with that which database you are connected to SSMS serverless or dedicated sql?

When I tried to change the collation of the lake database using the code below:
ALTER DATABASE [Dbname] COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8;

I faced the same error as shown below:

According to this MS document, the above error is returned if you are trying to modify a Lake database, create external tables, external data sources, database scoped credentials, or other objects in your Lake database. These objects can only be created on SQL databases.
Only the following operations are allowed in the Lake databases:

Creating, dropping, or altering views, procedures, and inline table-value functions (iTVF) in schemas other than dbo.
Creating and dropping the database users from Microsoft Entra ID.
Adding or removing database users from the db_datareader schema.


Thanks Bhavani, Have you come across a method where we can run queries without the case sensitivity?

check this MS document once?
